# HTML table each row(tr) is having different column(td) numbers

Tags: html, angular, html-table, tr, html-tbody

I am creating one table with pure HTML code (i.e. without any 3rd party library or bootstrap)
Here is my code :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rilymn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

I want table structure like this : (not talking about CSS,, HTML structure)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAKOy.png)

but the o/p is not as expected.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 mistakes in your HTML hierarchy.

1. You are wrapping some rows in a `div`. Try to change this to `ng-container` in order to not add additional nodes in your DOM, like `<ng-container *ngFor="let nameDatas of getMarksData">`.
2. You are basically wrapping every row of your table in a dedicated cell, when you have the following code:

```
...
<tr>
  <td>
    <tr *ngFor="let jj of nameDatas.subMarkData">
...
```

Try to just remove the `tr` and `td` node and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply @Fabian Strathaus , I tried as you said, removed extra tr td node. But no luck. getting result as before.

Comment: Did you implement both hints I made? In your Stackblitz example it seems like you only adjusted the second hint.

Comment: Yes.. Now it's working as expected. Thank you @Fabian Strathaus!